# Python script version

Tags: python, automation, version

I have multiple git hub repositories which have python scripts in it. I have around 200 scripts in 6 repositories. I need to find the scripts written on 2.7 and scripts written on 3 or above python version.

Notes: The scripts are used to run on different resources like lambda, ec2 etc it's not easy to run all the scripts because it needs a lot of dependencies to execute

I cannot use sys module in each script to check the version because its time consuming
Can someone please help

Comment: You could check whether the [shebang](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is defined for python3? Also, you can use language specificities such as "print xxx" vs "print(xxx)" to discriminate between both versions. Can you give an example of those scripts ?

Comment: shebang is not defined in the script.
If I have to view I need to view all the 200 python scripts to make sure it's on the latest version or the older version. Do we have any programmatic way to check this? @mozway

Comment: There are likely programmatic ways, but to determine this can you give some examples of the scripts?